# Android Actionbar navigation spinner text color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I am able to change the background of the navigation spinner:

```
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
    </style>

  <style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="android:style/Widget.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    </style>
```

Nevertheless the textColor is not changed. I also tried other ways to change the textColor:

```
 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">?color_actionbar</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
    </style>

  <style name="myTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/violet</item>
    </style>
```

Any other idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was looking for the same answer but didn't find anything, so I tried this solution. I works for me at least.

In the themes file, you can set the style for the spinnerDropdownItemStyle:

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="YourParentTheme">
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/YourCustomDropDownItemStyle</item>
</style>
```

Now, set the textappearance for your style:

```
<style name="YourCustomDropDownItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/YourCustomDropDownItemTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

And in your custom textappearance you can set the text details:

```
<style name="YourCustomDropDownItemTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Here you can set the color and other text attributes -->
</style>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget

Comment: @Mike If you're using Sherlok Action Bar, use `parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title"`, if not, it should be something similar.

Comment: He forgot to add `android:` in front of the `Widget`

Comment: can you please elaborate how to use it? and what about this parent theme?

Comment: I have this error,.. No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:textColor' with value '@color/white')..

Comment: The text color is not changing for me.