# Android action bar spinner text colour

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and want to change the colour of the text in the action bar nav spinner. Could somebody please provide an example of the xml required to do this?

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried? where you failed to achieve your goal? share code snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ended up using a custom spinner item layout with a text view with white text:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:paddingLeft="10dp"
          android:textSize="18sp"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: That's the only working solution for me. 
Adjust actionDropDownStyle and add set textAppearance does not work for me.

Comment: I tried following [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) , but it didn't work for me. Changing the color directly on the TextView did work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="YourParentTheme">
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/YourCustomDropDownItemStyle</item>
</style>
```

Now, set the textappearance for your style:

```
<style name="YourCustomDropDownItemStyle" parent="Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/YourCustomDropDownItemTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

And in your custom textappearance you can set the text details:

```
<style name="YourCustomDropDownItemTextStyle" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Here you can set the color and other text attributes -->
</style>
```

Sources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502759/1412308) and same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395381/android-actionbar-navigation-spinner-text-color)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. That seems to change the colour of the text in the drop down items of the spinner. What I actually want to do is change the colour of the spinner in the action bar.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer, I needed two resources as the action bar needed White, but the drop down needed standard black

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
 getActivity().getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                        R.layout.spinner_custom_item, names);

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

Under res/values/themes.xml

```
<style name="MY_THEME" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/SpinnerSelector</item>
</style>
```

Under res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="SpinnerSelector">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_selector</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

Under res/drawable/spinner_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_normal" />
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_disabled" android:text="#FFFFFF"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true"       android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_selected" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"     android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_normal" />
<item android:state_focused="true"     android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_disabled"  android:text="#FFFFFF"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_dropdown_disabled" />

</selector>
```

In Activity,

```
Spinner mSpnrTranscationType = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.transaction_type_list,
                R.layout.spinner_item_white);
adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mSpnrTranscationType.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

Under res/layout/spinner_item_white.xml,

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="@color/white" />
```