# ActionBar list navigation: different text color in header and pop up menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a navigation list in my action bar that has a dark background. The pop menu however, has a white background.

So what I want to achieve is, that the item text color inside of the action bar is white whereas the items text color in the menu pop up are black.

This are two examples what I got so far:

[image: bad examples]

This is how it should look like:

[image: planned]

Does anyone know a solution?

This is my code for the list navigation:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2" });

getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter,
        new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
                return true;
            }
        });

getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(0)
```

These is a collection of styles that I worked with.

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.customized">
      <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
      <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
      <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/CustomSherlockDropDownNav</item>
      <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/CustomSherlockDropDownNav</item>

      <!-- didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395381/android-actionbar-navigation-spinner-text-color           
      <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/custom.Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
      <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/custom.Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
      -->

      <!-- didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479186/styling-actionbar-dropdown-menu 
      <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/custom.actionBarWidgetTheme</item>
      <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/custom.actionBarWidgetTheme</item>
      -->

      <!-- didn't work: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html                                                                        
      <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/CustomDropDownListView</item>
      <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/CustomDropDownListView</item>
      -->

      ....  
</style>


<style name="custom.actionBarWidgetTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/custom.Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
</style>

<style name="custom.Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/custom.TextAppearance.Widget.DropDownItem</item>
</style>

<style name="custom.TextAppearance.Widget.DropDownItem" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.DropDownItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00A000</item>
</style>


<style name="CustomDropDownListView" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
  <item name="android:textColor">#00A000</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">8dip</item>
</style>


<style name="CustomSherlockDropDownNav" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
      <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_customtab</item>
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_customtab</item>
</style>
```

However nothing didn't work.

Comment: how did you do this ? can you post a working code ?

Comment: @user2247689: currently I've no access to the sources. Basically I started with what *matthias* proposed: applying two different layouts and setting custom styles for them (overriding `textAppearance`; see my comment). I'd recommend that you have a look at ActionBarSherlock, 'cause you can quickly look up the linked style sources. Later I changed my implementation to the solution of *Android-Developer*, because I've more than one `Spinner` in my app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I got the thing to work :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same resource `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line` for the spinner item and the spinner dropdown item.

Use `R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item` and `R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item` instead.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2" });
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

This way, the styles like `Widget.Sherlock.TextView.SpinnerItem` will work.

Comment: This pointed me into the right direction. I wasn't aware of the right layouts and (consequently) styles to apply. I got it finally running with layouts above and adding `spinnerItemStyle` and `spinnerDropDownItemStyle` to the main theme. The actual changes on text color and size can be done in derived `textAppearance` styles.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this just creating your custom xml which will be your list item. Create your xml like this :
**custom_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/holo_dark_red"
    android:paddingRight="110dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

and use it like this :

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_list_item);
```

That should do the trick (at least it's working in my apps).

Comment: this works great and is definitely a valuable hint in particular for those cases where the standard layout is not sufficient. However, I'm happy with the pre-defined layout here. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Great answer for those who don't want to deal with the styles file!

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="Theme.WhyCheck" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Item.Inverse</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Item.Inverse" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/ActionBar.TitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.TitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Should be like this. Don't know why using spinner"Item"Style @@

Comment: I'm using ActionBarSherlock (see tags above). Meanwhile I've implemented a custom view as _Android-Developer_ suggested. Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: Hope u can get some tips by AppCompat theme style

Answer (score 0):

```
         @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        // Inflating the layout for the custom Spinner
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);

        // Declaring and Typecasting the textview in the inflated layout
        TextView tvLanguage = (TextView) layout
        .findViewById(R.id.tvLanguage);

        // Setting the text using the array
        tvLanguage.setText(obj[position]);

        //tvLanguage.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tvLanguage.setTextSize(14f);




        return layout;

    }
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customdropdown, null);

        // Declaring and Typecasting the textview in the inflated layout
        TextView tvLanguage = (TextView) layout
        .findViewById(R.id.tvLanguage);

        // Setting the text using the array
        tvLanguage.setText(obj[position]);

        //tvLanguage.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tvLanguage.setTextSize(14f);



        return layout;
    }

}
```

Comment: don't forget to use two custom layout.