# Why is the text black instead of white when I create a navigation dropdown in an ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

NOTE: this is my first Android app and I have no clue what I am doing.  Directing me to the documentation without explaining what I should be looking for will not be helpful as I have attempted to read the documentation already and have not understood it.

I am creating a navigation dropdown in the ActionBar and the text is black instead of white (like the rest of the text in my ActionBar).  I assume this is because I am using the wrong thing in my ArrayAdapter, but none of the other values work any better.  What follows is the code I am using to create the dropdown.

```
//NOTE: folders will be created at runtime from data fetched from a web service,
//these values are just test data to get the feature working
folders = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("All Folders", "comics"));
final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
    this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    folders
);

final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(aa, new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener() {
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        final Context c = getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(c, folders.get(itemPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Example of what I am seeing:

[image: black text on gray background]

I want to understand why the text is the wrong color, and hopefully how to create it with the right color.  I do not want to customize the color (like a lot of the questions I have found), I just want it to be created in the same style as the rest of the stuff in the ActionBar.

This the styles.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: The source code for `simple_list_item_1` does nothing in the way of setting a text color so it stands to reason that it would attempt to follow the app's theme. What I've mistakenly done before is make views  and change the theme in each view realizing later that if I changed the app theme to what I wanted to be consistent across the entire app everything behaves as expected without changing anything programmatically. Could it be possible that your theme-ing is causing this issue?

Comment: Could you please post the theme you're using? You can find it in the `styles.xml` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I suspected, all of the jiggery-pokery with styles people were suggesting was just patching over code that was doing the wrong thing in the first place.  The code in `onCreate` should have looked like this:

```
    // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(
            // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    actionBar.getThemedContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    new String[] {
                            "All Folders",
                            "comics",
                            "test"
                    }),
            this);
```

and I should have had an `onNavigationItemSelected` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
    // When the given dropdown item is selected, show its contents in the
    // container view.

    return true;
}
```

The key part of this is the `actionBar.getThemedContext()` method.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Chas. Owens reply actionBar.getThemedContext() works great if you are on Jellybean and above.

For others ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), ...) works just as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose a style for that activity/application. Refer to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395381/android-actionbar-navigation-spinner-text-color) to make the navigation item white.

Comment: I saw that, it didn't work for me.  Either I did something wrong that that answer doesn't explain well enough, or it doesn't apply to what is wrong.  It also doesn't answer my question, which is "Why is the text black instead of white...".  I asked this question in this way because I want to understand why it is broken.  Also, I can't believe that Android is so fundamentally broken that you have to jump through hoops to do something this simple.  They made it so easy to add a navigation drop down that I can't believe that you have to implement your own style to make it work properly.

Comment: Ideally setting the style should work. Try this in OnnavigationItemSelected ; ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE); This will explicitly set the textcolor of textview to white.

Answer (score -2):

The bar.getThemedContext() trick worked for me. Just like you, I wandered a long time why the text was black instead of white. I would not have found that myself.