# change ActionBar Spinner text color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner, android-appcompat

I already read many ways to change spinner textColor in an ActionBar, but I really can't figure it out what is missing to make what I need.

This is how I have my actionbar spinner:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I have white text on spinner items. I need to change it to black.

My res/styles file is this one.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/MyDropDownItemView</item>
        <!-- <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item> -->
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyDropDownListView" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I changed background to white, but now i need to change text to black and I can't do it.

Some one can help me?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to create a custom spinner item layout for your spinner, but with only a textview & it's color set to whatever you want it to be.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:gravity="center"       
          android:textSize="14sp"
          android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Here is also a post that explains how to do it by changing the xml styles: [Android Actionbar navigation spinner text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395381/android-actionbar-navigation-spinner-text-color?rq=1)

**UPDATE:**

Remove the "android:" part from the xml statments that change something from the appcompat library. In my app it did the trick. So instead of this:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/MyDropDownItemView</item>
        <!-- <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item> -->
    </style>
```

You remove the "android:" part:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
        <item name="dropDownItemStyle">@style/MyDropDownItemView</item>
        <!-- <item name="textColor">@color/white</item> -->
    </style>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

So i'll just post how i style my appcompat apps, so maybe you can see what i don't see. I have 2 folders: resources/values & resources/values-v14.

In the resource/value my style.xml file looks like this:

```
  <style name="Theme.Jamesstyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Actionbar.FlatUi</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBar.FlatUi.Tabs</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.FlatUi.Text</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Actionbar.FlatUi" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@color/bizzumi_light</item>
        <item name="backgroundStacked">@color/bizzumi_red</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/bizzumi_red</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleColor</item>
        <item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="TitleColor" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="textColor">#000099</item>
    </style>
```

And in my resources/values-v14 style.xml file i have:

```
<style name="Theme.Jamesstyle" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Actionbar.FlatUi</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBar.FlatUi.Tabs</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.FlatUi.Text</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Actionbar.FlatUi" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/bizzumi_light</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/bizzumi_light</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/bizzumi_light</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleColor</item>i
         <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item><item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item></style>
    <style name="TitleColor" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000099</item>
    </style>
```

Maybe try this folder structure and create 2 different styles.xml files. Otherwise i'm clueless. Good luck!

Comment: I tried to do what is in the link but without success

Comment: Try removing the "android:" part in the xml statements that change an appcompat element ( like that spinner ). With the appcompat library, it's a different way of changing the style. So your declartion would look a little something like this: 

<style name="YourTheme" parent="YourParentTheme">
    <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/YourCustomDropDownItemStyle</item>
</style>

Comment: I've updated my question, because the formatting of code in the comment section isn't that easy to read.

Comment: I'm sorry buddy, i'll try one more time, but thats the last suggestion i can make, check my answer.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet. I have other things to do. but you tried to help me so...

Comment: Thx! I'm just curious :) Let me know if you have tested it!

Comment: nothing works. I also tried with a spinnerAdapter, but i still can't give a color for spinner and others colours to the items.

Answer (score 0):

```
`<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/MyDropDownItemView</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item> -->
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyDropDownListView" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```